# Dash Uploader will not work with files above 1Mb

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This uploader is for `.xlsx` files. It doesn't work with files above 1.0Mb, but works fine with files smaller than this.

I have `max_file_size` set well above this.

Running this locally, I can upload any size file without a problem - it is only an issue with the version that is deployed here:

[link to Elastic Beanstalk app](http://testinguploader-env.eba-bvskm8aq.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

```
import dash_uploader as du
import dash
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#application = app.server

du.configure_upload(app, r'')

app.layout = html.Div([
    du.Upload(
        text='Drag and Drop Here',
        text_completed='Successful Upload of ',
        id='upload',
        max_file_size=18000,
        max_files=1,
        filetypes=['xlsx'],
        upload_id= 'uploader_id'
    ),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #application.run_server(port=8080)
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: try checking this out, maybe it's something to do with nginx limiting the message size - https://dev.to/rasoolk16/elastic-beanstalk-update-media-upload-size-53go#:~:text=After%20adding%20this%20file%2C%20deploy,file%20up%20to%20size%20100MB.

Comment: spot on fix. thank you!